# Azure Function - js - not running correctly, but no error in the logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

Am trying to build a Function to get data from my IoTHub and send the data to my web service via GET.

This is what I have in my Function:

```
var http = require('https');
module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {

    IoTHubMessages.forEach(message => {
        // context.log(`Processing message9: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
        console.log(`what the what???`);
        let url = `<my site in Azure>.azurewebsites.net`;
        console.log(url);
        let path = "/sensor/" + message.d1 + "/" + message.d2 + "/" + message.d3 + "/";
        console.log(path);
        var req = http.request({
            host: url,
            path: path,
            method: 'GET'
        });
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });
        req.on('end', function(e) {
            console.log('finished with request');
        });

        req.end();
    });

    context.done();
};
```

The logs look like this:

```
2019-02-10T06:06:22.503 [Information] Executing 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Reason='', Id=ea6109b0-5037-4f15-9efc-845222c6f404)
2019-02-10T06:06:22.512 [Information] Executed 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Succeeded, Id=ea6109b0-5037-4f15-9efc-845222c6f404)
2019-02-10T06:06:22.786 [Information] Executing 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Reason='', Id=f344c44f-a6ff-49b3-badb-58429b3476dc)
2019-02-10T06:06:22.796 [Information] Executed 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Succeeded, Id=f344c44f-a6ff-49b3-badb-58429b3476dc)
```

If I uncomment this line :

```
context.log(`Processing message9: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
```

then the JSON data is displayed in the log output. In between the Executing and Executed pairs I see:

```
2019-02-10T05:59:28.906 [Information] Processing message9: {"topic":"iot","d1":"200","d2":"200","d3":"200"}
```

- I am not getting my GET request
- I don't see the `console.log` messages after the initial stringify line
- I don't see any errors.

I've tried different quotation marks to see if Node preferred one or the other.

Occasionally when restarting the Function I see a message like this in the log, but ignored it as the log had my JSON string

```
2019-02-10T06:00:10.600 [Error] Executed 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Failed, Id=2b3959cd-5014-4c50-89a3-77e37f2a890e)

Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'Object') uses Json.NET serialization. 
1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'Object' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed:
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Comment: Maybe start with replacing the 5 `console.log` with `context.log`?

Comment: You are likely calling `context.done` before the requests have finished. After `context.done` is called function execution is supposed to end so you won't see more logs, but you'll keep processing whatever what was left in the event loop.
I would try removing the existing `context.done` call and replace it with a global counter that add on `req.end` and an exit conditon when it matches`if(counter === IoTHubMessages.length) {context.done();}`. 
On the other hand to improve performance you may want to pass an Agent with `keepAlive:true` https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options

Comment: @Stock Overflaw - Wrote the console from muscle memory - didn't even notice that it was context on the one that worked.

Comment: Muscle is overrated: patience and fresh eyes do more than force and rage, as some long dead poet said. So your issue is sorted out then? (Since, well, your code seems OK from here, except for the point @nelak made: your `context.done` might be called too early if you want to do something in `req`'s listeners)

Comment: @StockOverflaw I changed to .C# and it worked as expected. Before doing so I tried the various suggestions here with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `forEach` loop is not a loop that is waiting for the result before calling `context.done`

When this happens as [@nelak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613865/azure-function-js-not-running-correctly-but-no-error-in-the-logs#comment96024571_54613865) points out in his comment, the azure function stops and nothing else happens.

Observe the following. I decided to replace the `http` library for a simple `setTimeout` function, but this is more or less the same. What is happening with your code, is ilustrated in the next snippet, notice the order in which the `console.log` are called.

```js
const myFn = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    IoTHubMessages.forEach(message => {
        console.log('inside foreach!')
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('inside settimeout, this is when your request is answered!')
        }, 1)
    });

    console.log('outside all!')
};

myFn(null, [0, 1])
```

If you waned a different behaviour you could rewrite this with the `async-await` pattern and then it seems syncronous but it's actually asynchronous.

```js
var callIt = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('inside settimeout!')
            return resolve('ok')
        }, 1)
    })
}
var myFnAwait = async (context, IoTHubMessages) => {
    for (i of IoTHubMessages){
        console.log('before settimeout')
        await callIt()
        console.log('after timeout')
    }

    console.log('outside all!')
};

myFnAwait(null, [0, 1])
```